# Google Sheets REST API 4 get row with specific column

Tags: rest, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to get only one row that contain specific value in one column.

How to make query and set something like: IF "column1" = '3' return that row?

If i use sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGetByDataFilter
i don't know what to write in DataFilter (now i write only "A:D" to return all rows and columns)

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<Sheet_ID>/values:batchGetByDataFilter?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
 
{
 "dataFilters": [
  {
   "a1Range": "A:D"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171179/get-filtered-data-from-google-sheets-api-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1