# Get filtered data from Google Sheets API with python?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

didn't found an answer.
Is it possible to use Python Google sheets API e.g. `service.spreadsheets().get()` to get data from spreadsheet only matching some criteria.
For example from
[this spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AtvV.png)

I want to get names with timestamp older than 5/3/2020 12:00:00. Is it possible to get, or I need to retrieve all data and filter with script?

Thanks, and sorry for screenshot outside of topic.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet#booleancriteria `BooleanCriteria.DATE_AFTER`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, it seems that I'm looking for. But how to put this into ```service.spreadsheets().values()``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to retrieve a filtered range using the Sheets API in python.

Either you apply a filter to the entire range directly in your code or you can use Google Visualization API. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48820107/7453656) you can find a guide on how to use the Google Visualization API with the Spreadsheet. Note that you will have to make your google sheet public in this case.

### Reference

[Google visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)